# If statement never returning true when I first hide the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, checkbox

```
$('.checkbox').on('change', function() {
  $('.pagination').hide();
  $('.callout').hide();

  $('.checkbox').each(function() {
    if ($(this).prop('checked') === true) {
    var checkboxName = $(this).val();

      $('.callout').each(function() {
        var calloutArray = $(this).data();
        var i;
          for (i = 0; i < calloutArray.category.length; i++) {
            $(this).hide();

            if (checkboxName === calloutArray.category[i]) {
               $(this).show();
            }
          }

      });
    }
   });
 });
```

To explain this function it basically listens to see if a checkbox has been clicked and then hides all the callouts on the page.

It then loops through each one of those checkboxes and checks which ones are true on the page. I then create a variable that stores the current checkbox value.

After this I then want to loop through each callout and pull its data from a data attribute.

I then loop through each string in the array and hide the callout no matter what. However if the callout has an array value that is the same as the checkbox value then I need to show it.

This seems to be working without the hide. However I need to hide the callouts if they do not hold the same checked category names which is where I'm running into problems.

The If statement seems to never return true if I have already hidden the callout. So the question is how do I show the callout if the selected checkboxes match one of the callout array strings but hide the callout if the string is not in the callout array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I've understand, the following code is equivalent

```
$('.checkbox').on('change', function () {
    $('.pagination, .callout').hide();

    $('.checkbox:checked').each(function () {
        var checkboxName = $(this).val();

        $('.callout').hide().each(function () {
            var calloutArray = $(this).data();

            if (calloutArray.category.indexOf(checkboxName) !== -1) {
                $(this).show();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

1. Merge selectors having common actions(`hide()`)
2. Use `:checked` pseudo-selector to select only checked elements
3. Use `hide()` on selector and then iterate over it using `each()`
4. Use `indexOf` to check if element is in array

Comment: As I've pointed out many times before, *explanation* is at least as important as code. Rather than racing to post code without any explanation to be "first in line," explain in your *initial answer*. You don't know that SO won't go down, your internet connection may fail, etc.

Comment: Brilliant thanks for hte explaination. I  see where I went wrong now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're showing/hiding your element on **each iteration of the loop**. That means the result of the *last* iteration wins, as though you hadn't done the earlier ones at all.

You can just use `Array#indexOf` to see if the name is in the array, and use the resulting flag to show/hide the callout:

```
$(this).toggle(calloutArray.category.indexOf(checkboxName) != -1);
```

E.g.:

```
$('.checkbox').on('change', function() {
    $('.pagination').hide();
    $('.callout').hide();

    $('.checkbox').each(function() {
        if ($(this).prop('checked') === true) {
            var checkboxName = $(this).val();

            $('.callout').each(function() {
                var calloutArray = $(this).data();
                $(this).toggle(calloutArray.category.indexOf(checkboxName) != -1);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Also note that

```
if ($(this).prop('checked') === true) {
```

is quite a long way to write

```
if (this.checked) {
```

Similarly, with `input`elements, `this.value` is the same as `$(this).val()`.

Comment: `$('.checkbox').each(function() {
        if ($(this).prop('checked') === true) {` ==> `$('.checkbox:checked').each(function() {`

Comment: @Tushar: If you want to force jQuery to bypass the browser's built-in selector engine, yes.